# Hiding UI elements behind an image

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to achieve to hide my UI elements such as text, images etc. behind another transparent image. The problem is that I am using the latest Unity version and these custom shaders have no effect on hiding the UI shaders. The two custom shaders I have applied for testing are:

```
Shader "Custom/DepthReserve"
{
    Properties
    {
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" "Queue"="Geometry-1" }
        LOD 100

        Blend Zero One

        Pass
        {

        }
    }
}
```

and

```
Shader "Custom/InvisibleMask" {
  SubShader {
    // draw after all opaque objects (queue = 2001):
    Tags { "Queue"="Geometry+1" }
    Pass {
      Blend Zero One // keep the image behind it
    }
  } 
}
```

So is there a way to use a transparent image to hide text, images and even gameobjects?

Comment: How about SetActive method to hide/show objects? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html

Comment: @unobatbayar No, I am trying very different than to activate/deactivate gameObjects.

Comment: I see, maybe check here https://answers.unity.com/questions/1745487/how-to-hide-objects-inside-of-or-behind-another-tr.html

Comment: @unobatbayar yup I tried that as well. No luck,

Comment: Maybe use a [`Mask`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-Mask.html) ... ?